# How to read ERC1155's SafeTransferFrom() transactions in golang?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, erc-1155, golang

Trying to read `ERC1155` `SafeTransferFrom` events, in `golang`.

Here is what I tried:

```
var (
    // erc 1155
    logSafeTransferFromSig     = []byte("SafeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,uint256,bytes)")
    logSafeTransferFromSigHash = crypto.Keccak256Hash(logSafeTransferFromSig)
)
```

When try to match the event via:

```
switch vLog.Topics[0].Hex() {
    case logSafeTransferFromSigHash.Hex(): // ERC1155 - safeTransferFrom()
```

`TransferSingle` events on [this page](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x289A1726C00013e1563e6A0442A1d4B34F169072#events) are not matched.

So how should variable `logSafeTransferFromSig` be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out:

**sig hash:**

```
    EventNameTransferSingle  = "TransferSingle"
    logTransferSingleSig     = []byte(EventNameTransferSingle + "(address,address,address,uint256,uint256)")
    logTransferSingleSigHash = crypto.Keccak256Hash(logTransferSingleSig)
```

**event struct:**

```
type Erc1155LogTransferSingle struct {
    Operator common.Address
    From     common.Address
    To       common.Address
    Id       *big.Int
    Value    *big.Int
}
```

---

**Example query result from my program:**

```
(# 0) transaction log:
    block = 7632194, tx = 0xf597e0f3e6822d1b7accc91b71fff9131eddda8528541aa7c198ace3b12d1709, address = 0x289A1726C00013e1563e6A0442A1d4B34F169072
    log index: 93
    topic 0: 0xc3d58168c5ae7397731d063d5bbf3d657854427343f4c083240f7aacaa2d0f62
    Log Name: TransferSingle
    From: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    To: 0xe38fE38eB33950E21Fa9419178A27C9Be553330A
    token Id: 0
    Value: 1000000000000000000

(# 1) transaction log:
    block = 7632194, tx = 0xf597e0f3e6822d1b7accc91b71fff9131eddda8528541aa7c198ace3b12d1709, address = 0x289A1726C00013e1563e6A0442A1d4B34F169072
    log index: 94
    topic 0: 0xc3d58168c5ae7397731d063d5bbf3d657854427343f4c083240f7aacaa2d0f62
    Log Name: TransferSingle
    From: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    To: 0xe38fE38eB33950E21Fa9419178A27C9Be553330A
    token Id: 1
    Value: 1000000000000000000000000000
```